# facebook PHP SDK redirect_uri to page tab

Tags: php, facebook, sdk, tabs

im using the PHP SDK to get user to authorize my app. the thing that is a bit tricky is that i;m doing this inside a tab. the redirect uri will break the tab 'iframe' and just open as a normal app,i do not want this. how can i keep it inside the page tab iframe. below is my code;

```
<?php

include("utility.php");
include("db_setup.php");
require_once "base_facebook.php";
require("facebook.php");
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => 'xxxxxx',
    'secret' => 'xxxxxx',
));

$conn = connectUserDB();
$user = $facebook->getUser();
if ($user) {
    try {
        // Proceed knowing you have a logged in user who's authenticated.

          //$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me?fields=name,id,email');

header( 'Location: submitted.php' ) ;

       } catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
    //print_r($e);
        $user = null;
    }
}
// $user is null : $user is either not logged in or the token is not valid
else if(!$user) { 
$params = array(
'scope' => 'email',
'redirect_uri' => 'submitted.php'
);

$loginUrl = $facebook ->getLoginUrl($params);

echo '<script type="text/javascript">';
echo 'top.location.href = " '.$loginUrl.' " ; ';
echo '</script>';
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to log in user without having him/her leave your tab, you could use [javascript SDK](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/) (you can call function [FB.login()](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/#login) which will open popup).

If you want to keep using php, on your "normal app" (the page that gets opened in iframe on Facebook) you can simply make a redirect back to your tab on Facebook. So that after user gets logged in and redirected to your page, you redirect him back to Facebook tab.

Comment: i want to keep using the php. i tried redirecting it back to tab, but theres a problem with ipads.

Comment: what exactly is the problem with ipads?

Comment: i tried redirecting it back to main page of the tab (http://www.facebook.com/pagename/app_3917315842xxxx) but when i click the button to go to main page, it keeps on coming back to the tab url.

Comment: Does this only occur on iPad or also in browser or other devices?

Comment: its only on the ipad. chrome is okay.

Comment: Is iPad, by any chance, using Safari to browse web pages? Because if it does, then there's an issue in default privacy setting for Safari, which prevents it from accepting third party cookies (that's the kind of cookie that is being set when logging user in).

Comment: i used the native facebook app. solved the problem actually. redirection went wrong. thanks for your help though :)